# MySQL convert data in float field to decimal field

Tags: mysql, database

I have some data in a MySQL table that was mistakenly stored as a `float` data type. For example:

`7.45`

I need to convert that data to a `decimal` type so that I don't run into rounding errors going forward.

If I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE `invoice_line`
CHANGE `line_quantity` `line_quantity` decimal(18,6) unsigned NOT NULL AFTER `line_rate`;
```

I end up with values like this in my table:

`70.449997`

How can I correctly convert the data over to `decimal` without mangling the data?

Comment: it's to be expected. floats cannot exactly represent decimal-based numbers. the data in the db has already been mangled somewhat by the conversion to float, and getting back the original unmangled numbers is basically impossible. you'd need the original source of the numbers BEFORE they want into the db, so you can be assured you're actually putting in the right values.

Comment: While I understand that this is expected behavior, that doesn't actually help me fix it the problem...

Comment: the solution is to go back to original data. you can't trust what's in the db. a value might naturally have been 7.449, or it might have 7.5 and got mangled to 7.449. there's no way to tell now.

Comment: The data in the floats *is* correct as it displays when doing a SELECT statement. The data in the floats is what I want. The problem is that when I convert it to DECIMAL, the value that's put in the DECIMAL is not the same as what was in the float. e.g. if I see 7.45 in the FLOAT then I want to see 7.45000 in the DECIMAL. Not 7.449997.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `mysqldump` (or MySQL Workbench has a utility as well) to dump the table. Then do your `ALTER` and recreate it. Just adding precision is going to introduce errors like this because floating point numbers are generally imprecise anyways.